# How to identify Google calendar 'Out of office' events using Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need a way to identify if a given Google calendar event is an 'Out of office' event using the Google Calendar API.

Previously I used to check the 'description' field of the event object, but it seems that Google has discontinued sending that field.

Simply, what I need to find is whether a Google user is on Vacation/Out-of-office on a given date. Thanks.

Comment: welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your currnt solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### When you create an `Out of office` event, this becomes the summary - not the description - of the event.

You can query with [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)
, simply  setting the free text search parameter `q` to `"Out of office"` and should obtain a response looking like the following:

```js
{
  "kind": "calendar#events",
    ...
    "items": [
      {
        ...
        "created": "2020-11-11T08:19:11.000Z",
        "updated": "2020-11-11T08:19:11.213Z",
        "summary": "Out of office",
        "creator": {
        "email": "XXX",
        "self": true
      },
      ...
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The  "Out of office" is editable. So if somebody changes the field to "Personal time off" you will not be able to identify the event as OOO. 

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617844/how-do-i-create-an-out-of-office-type-calendar-event-via-the-rest-api) and the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112063903).

In short there is no official way. The best way I found is,that OOO events have no attendees.

Comment: An Event in the 'items' will contain this field: "eventType": "outOfOffice". I don't think you can make this part of your query, but there is the option to check this value in your app